# Is there a right way to define additional packages for asset specification in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid

I have several pyramid projects I'm combining into a single projects with jinja files that have lines like:

```
{% extends 'some_project:templates/layout.jinja2'%}
```

and

```
{% extends 'other_project:templates/layout.jinja2'%}
```

It would be great if I could simply put all the sub project files into subfolders then register an additional asset specification so `some_project:templates/` got turned into `combo_projects:templates/some_project/templates` and I wouldn't have to touch any of the templates.

I added...

```
config.override_asset(to_override='other_project:templates/', override_with='combo_projects:templates/some_project/templates'
```

...which initially complained about missing module `other_project`, so I made a dummy module and things seem to work but I'm worried I've abused the system and am standing on a house of cards.

Is there a better way to do this?  Reading the docs on asset specifications https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/assets.html#asset-specifications or on overriding linked in it aren't giving me any insight.

Obviously I could also update all the files, which I might, but I want to know if I what I did is safe and if there is a better way to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Pyramid a real module prefix is required to override an asset, but that's it. Now that you've made a module and reserved that namespace, what you're doing is not what I'd consider an abuse of the system.